# unable to restore the backup in sql server

Tags: sql-server

I am using SQL Server 2008. When I tried to restore backup from SQL Server Management Studio (or) using query, I got the access denied error.

```
Cannot open backup device 'C:\Backup\101015.bak'. Operating system error 5(Access is denied.).
```

I have tried both "sa" account and windows authentication. I am the administrator for the machine. But still it throws access denied. Please help me.

Comment: and the programming related bit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try checking the permissions and ownership on the .bak file you are trying to restore. Right click it in windows explorer.

Select Properties - Security - Advanced.

Under Owner tab make sure Administrators group is current owner, if not use "replace owner on subcontainers and objects" option.

Check permissions too.

If not sure you could try adding Administrator read,write permissions to the file. Worst case try adding "Everyone" permissions, but just to that file - you can always remove these when finished to retain proper security.

That's not the default backup location for SQL...how/where did the backup come from? Manually via Studio Management? What permissions does the C:\Backup\ folder have?

Comment: I moved the file to D: and it worked :)

Answer (score 0):

The account that the SQL Server service is running under is account that needs access to the backup file.

Comment: SQL server is running under NETWORK Service account. Do I need to change that to administrator?

Answer (score 0):

Move the file to your default sql backup location.  It will be something like c:\program files\microsoft sql server\MSSQL.1\MSSQL\Backup.

Security rights for the SQL account should not be changed in most situations.

Comment: Initially it was in SQL Backup folder only. Since it gave problem here, I moved to c:\backup